# Hide Base64 string from my material table cell

Tags: html, angular, image, angular-material, material-ui

I Have one material table in that I need to show user images. for those user Images, I'm passing base64 string from my ts file and it's showing images but the problem is that it's also showing base 64 string as well I don't know how to remove that string from my material cell. I want to show only image not string please help. the code as shown below.

> .html file

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="column?.type === 'image'">
                                    
    <img *ngIf="element['hasImage']" style="vertical-align: bottom;" [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,'+element[column?.property]" alt="image" height="40" width="40"> 
    
    </ng-container>
```

> Page Error

[Image of Insepect Elements in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7cqO.png)

You can see in this picture that I'm showing base64 image in "Img" tag successfully but I also got text of base64 image as well that I don't want to show.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing `{{ element[column?.property] }}` elsewhere in the template?

Comment: yes this is an unique property through out in table.

Comment: Please produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: When I bind data to table "isellipsisactive" is automatically gets enabled and base64 string is added as innerhtml in newly added div tag . I don't know the issue comes from here or not but I got base64 as text in div tag but I only need image tag.